# Root route pointing to show action Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a one page site and the controller is called 'home'. The home page is rendered from the show action. I also have a slug column in the database record called 'home'.

I need to change root route so instead of www.example.com/home/1 it should be www.example.com

Can friendly_id handle this? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using `show` instead of `index` action?

Comment: I need the index action to loop though the text I have for the show page. Its a one page site and the text of the page is stored in the database. So on the show page I have html and variables. Like a cms.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
root to: 'home#show'
```

to the `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: I did that but it couldn't find an id... error: Couldn't find Home without an ID

Comment: It's better to rename home/show action to home/index action. In controller and in routes.rb either.

Answer (score 0):

based on Kirti's question I moved everything in the index